# How to access url segment in controller in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am working in Laravel 5.2 and i want to access URL segments in my controller. I am using

```
echo  Request::segment(2);
```

but nothing is print. How can i get values from url in controller.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: @Ali After domain "public/admin/edit_country/2".

Comment: @Chillon not getting any error.

Comment: You need to you `Illuminate\Http\Request` fecade. If you are using any other.

Comment: Ali means; use Request;

Comment: @Ali i already use Request in my controller. If i am not using then it gives error.

Comment: Please show more code in this case. Perhaps the full controller?

Comment: @Chillon i include the required files in controller and passes "Request $request" argument in my function.

Comment: if your using method injection (which it seems like you are from the above comment) then try `$request->segment(2)` inside the method.

Comment: @steven thats why I ask for more code. Can't help in this way.

Answer (score 15):

In laravel 5.2 you can do it this way..

```
echo request()->segment(2);
```

request() is one of the several helper functions provided in Laravel 5.2. It returns the current request object thus you don't need use statement for the facade on the top of your class.

Comment: This is not an answer, merely an alternative for the way he is doing it right now. Both methods are totally acceptable.

Comment: I am using Laravel  5.1 and getting URL data with `$request->segment(3)` in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

> In Laravel 7, I am using this to get segments

```
public function my_function(Request $request )
{
    // By using this, we can get the second segment in route
    // Example: example.com/hh/kk
    
    $segment = $request->segment(2);

    // By using this we will get "kk"
}
```