# Why my active link on sidebar is not functioning?

Tags: php, laravel, sidebar

I already tried this 2 types of code which is `{{Request::is('residential') ? 'active' : ''}}` and `{{ 'contractor' == request()->path() ? 'active' : '' }}` But still nothing is happened. This is my whole code for **sidebar.blade.php**

```
<div id="sidebar-nav" class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-scroll">
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav">
              
                @if(auth()->user()->role == 'admin')
                    <li class="{{Request::is('residential') ? 'active' : ''}}">
                        <a href="/residential"><i class="lnr lnr-apartment"></i><span>Residence</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="{{ 'contractor' == request()->path() ? 'active' : '' }}">
                        <a href="/contractor"><i class="lnr lnr-magic-wand"></i><span>Contractor</span></a>
                    </li>
                @endif
                 
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth','checkRole:admin'], function () {
   Route::get('/residential','ResidentialController@index');
   Route::get('/contractor', 'ContractorController@index')->name('contractor')
}
```

What I suppose to do? I hope someone can help me to figure this out.

Comment: try `{{  Request::segment(1) == "contractor"? 'active' : '' }}`

Comment: Nope, nothing changed.

Comment: can u check `contractor` this word in url in `segment(1)` or `segment(0)` then apply condition  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37695512/how-to-access-url-segment-in-controller-in-laravel-5-2/37696008

Comment: what URL are you currently hitting?

Comment: i have the answer on another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63613735/requestis-only-work-on-parent-route-how-to-use-that-on-child-route/63666552#63666552